How to get Flask routing to work in shared hosting
I have built a minimal Flask application and installed it in Namecheap shared hosting, following the instructions in https://dev.to/lordghostx/how-to-host-flask-applications-on-namecheap-cpanel-299b. Here's the code:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/<string:name>/")
def say_hello(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

The code works perfectly on my local PC with the development server.
After installing in Namecheap, the "/" path works correctly, but the /string:name/ path gives a 404 (not found) error.
There is nothing in the application stderr log file.
There are many online posts about the failure of Flask routing, but none quite fits this situation.
Any help, please.

What specific path you are trying to access?

what python and flask version ur using

This bug is caused by NameCheaps Website Builder.
You can comment out the line below in your /public_html/.ht_access
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ncsitebuilder/$1 [L,QSA]

This may of course interfer with the sitebuilder site you created. Below is the answer that the insufferable AI-support chatat NameCheap finally produced after I did most of the troubleshooting for them. You only need to change the .ht_access though, not delete the other files.
NameCheap Chatbot answer
